# Select on many to many relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `products` table and an `orders` table. They have a many to many relationship between them and the `product_order` table is the intermediary. Now, I have two products ids and want to select the orders that contains both of them, if it exists. How can I do that with Laravel eloquent?

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'product_order');
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'product_order');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your models and relationships.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir updated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple `whereHas()` constraints:

```php
$productIds = [1, 2];
$query = Order::query();
foreach($productIds as $productId) {
    $query->whereHas('products', function($query) use($productId) {
        $query->where('products.id', $productId);
    });
}
$orders = $query->get();
```

If there can only be one pivot row for each combination of `order_id` and `product_id`, you can use a shorter query:

```php
$productIds = [1, 2];
$orders = Order::whereHas('products', function($query) use($productIds) {
    $query->whereIn('products.id', $productIds);
}, '=', count($productIds))->get();
```

Comment: I added a shorter alternative.